# How to use fonts in opengl in java?

Tags: java, opengl, fonts

The title pretty much sums it up - its the easiest thing in the
world in C++ and Windows, but Java seems to struggle with this issue.

I would like to stay away from solutions involving loading bitmaps of fonts, and instead try go for a native truetype font loader, if possible. Kerning and antialiasing is quite important in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the JOGL/Java 2D bridge: render the font on a texture.

Check out "Java 2D and JOGL"[1]

[1]: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/campbell/archive/2007/01/java_2d_and_jog.html ""

Answer (score 3):

JOGL has a class, TextRenderer, which should do what you want. It accepts a Java "Font" object, and I think you can specify any ttf file for such objects. It does also support antialiasing, I'm not sure what kerning is but probably that too. :)

Unfortunately the JOGL docs are currently... missing. Dunno where they went, hopefully they'll be back soon (in a day or two). Otherwise I would link you to the documentation for the class. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can do (e.g. if you want full lighting functionality for the text) is construct a [GlyphVector](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/GlyphVector.html) from the font and string and use a [GLUtessellator](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-beta5/javadoc_public/javax/media/opengl/glu/GLUtessellator.html) to render it as a set of triangles.

Answer (score 1):

JOGL is pretty good. I've used Processing (processing.org) before that renders nice text. Yes, C++ and OpenGL under Windows does seem easy as the Font management is different (Linux and MacOSX = Much harder to do text with OpenGL I've found)