# Drawing labels in JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, label, jogl

I am new to JOGL/OpenGL. How do I draw labels on a 2D rendered image using JOGL? Like in Java2D/Swing we use jlabel, what is the way to do it here?

Answer (score 5):

The `TextRenderer` class renders 2D and 3D labels. Here's some reference to help you get going:

```
TextRenderer textRenderer = new TextRenderer(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12));
textRenderer.beginRendering(900, 700);
textRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
textRenderer.setSmoothing(true);

DPoint pt = new DPoint(200, 200);
textRenderer.draw("Hello world!!", (int) (pt.x), (int) (pt.y));
textRenderer.endRendering();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL and specifically JOGL doesn't have a concept of labels. what you usually do is just freely render text in the JOGL window.
See this question for more details: [How to use fonts in opengl in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118026/how-to-use-fonts-in-opengl-in-java)

Here's another demo from Nehe that uses text but in a different way: http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/outline-fonts-nehe-tutorial-jogl-port.html