# OpenGL 3D text rendering

Tags: opengl, text, 3d, glut, jogl

Short of writing my own text rendering engine, is there any way I can import external fonts to use with `glutstrokecharacter` to render 3D text in OpenGL. (Just for clairty, this needs to be done using the JOGL API).

Answer (score 2):

`glutStrokeCharacter` uses built-in fonts. If you want to use custom font you need to use [TextRenderer](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs3421/jogl/javadoc_public/com/sun/opengl/util/j2d/TextRenderer.html). Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118026/how-to-use-fonts-in-opengl-in-java) for more options.

Comment: My understanding is that `TextRenderer` only supports bitmap fonts? I want to have text with depth.